# Creating a new mesh in Blender 2.7 through python

Tags: python, blender

I have a list of numbers domain, y, and z for the vertices and I tried filling in the faces too but I do not know why my mesh is not appearing? Is there something wrong in the format or a bug?

```
    numX = 3
    for i in range (0, numX):
            x = domain_list[numX]+2
            y = ry_list[numX]+2
            z = rz_list[numX]
            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.extend(vert)

    face = [(0, 1, 2)]
    faces.extend(face)
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(objname)
    objectme = bpy.data.objects.new(objname, me)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(objectme)
    me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
    me.update(calc_edges = True)
    objectme.location.x = px
    objectme.location.y = py
    objectme.location.z = pz
    return objectme
```

Comment: Can you post the values of `verts`, `domain_list`, `ry/z_list`, `px/y/z`? First things first: is the object well-formed in a visible region of the scene?

Comment: How do I know the object is in the scene?

Comment: Because you see it, but if your `px` variable is 1000 and your object is a triangle with side 0.1 then it's easy to miss it.

Comment: I cannot see my object nothing appears.

Comment: That's why we nees to see the values of `verts`, `domain_list`, `ry/z_list`, `px/y/z`, to see where the object should've been.